# Managing Tasks and Context in Visual Studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there option in Visual Studio Code like Managing Tasks and Context in JetBrains software (Webstorm, Phpstorm)?

Point is to keep open files in editor depend on task that somebody is working on.

Comment: Were you able to find that?

Comment: @Irina No, I have given up after some time...

Comment: Long shot but did you find anything that gets close to the task manager for vscode? I've found a couple plugins that seem to do the job but I'm very uncertain on which one might be best.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few different extensions that you could potentially use depending on your issue tracking software. JetBrains integrates with a bunch of different trackers, which you probably already know about, but for the benefit of those that don't, you can read about them [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-tasks-and-context.html#time_tracking).

When it comes to VSCode there doesn't appear to be anything which integrates so widely, so you may have to go down the route of looking for an extension that matches the issue tracking software you use. Here are a few:

- [Jira](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/jira-issues-in-vscode-969520918.html)
- [GitHub](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2020/05/06/github-issues-integration)
- [Trello](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Ho-Wan.vscode-trello-viewer)

Personally I use GitHub with Zenhub so I can see a kanban board for my issues. You can add new issues from the board itself and when you make changes in VSCode these flow through into Zenhub automatically.

Comment: I think the goal is not much to integrate a task manager to VS Code ; the goal is to have the open files depend on the task you are working on, and that when you sitch to a task you formerly worked on, then the open files of that task reopen as if you had never worked on anything else.